# using the value from resolv.conf in a config file

Tags: bash, configuration, resolv.conf

Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) generates as new `resolv.conf` file on every reboot with the content like so

```
nameserver 123.45.67.8
```

in the `~/.bashrc` file, I am using this value like below so that even when the namesever is changed (after every restart) everything works fine

```
export hostip=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ print $2 }')
export http_proxy="http://${hostip}:3128"
export HTTP_PROXY="http://${hostip}:3128"
export https_proxy="http://${hostip}:3128"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://${hostip}:3128"
export no_proxy="${hostip},127.0.0.1,::1,${hostip}*"
export NO_PROXY="${hostip},127.0.0.1,::1,${hostip}*"
```

This also works fine. However, I am creating a new configuration file for `apt` (for using apt-install , apt-get update , etc.). This file name & location is `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-proxyenv`

In this file I have the code below.

```
export hostip=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ print $2 }')
Acquire::http::proxy "http://${hostip}:3128";
Acquire::HTTP::PROXY "http://${hostip}:3128";
Acquire::HTTPS::PROXY "http://${hostip}:3128";
Acquire::https::proxy "http://${hostip}:3128";
```

This does not work. I get a syntax error `E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-proxyenv:1: Extra junk after value`. This error is related to line 1. How do I fix this?

Comment: You probably don't need `export` in the latter file and you probably want to terminate all lines including the first line with a semicolon `;` ... If that did not work move the first line to your `~/.profile` or `~/.login` file(*requires log out then log in afterwords*).

Comment: It did not work. I put the line `export hostip=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ print $2 }')` in both `~/.profile` and `~/.login` and tried. I get the error `Could not resolve '${hostip}'`

Comment: Then remove the first line and try command substitution directly like: `Acquire::http::proxy "http://$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ print $2 }'):3128";` and see if it works.

Comment: That also does not work. The error is `Could not resolve '$(cat '`

Comment: I am out of ideas ... let's wait for more ideas from other members.

Comment: @Raffa Thank you nonetheless for taking your time to providing suggestions.